# java : how to compare generic variables with int

Tags: java

Write a Java program to define a generic method that counts the number of elements in an array T [ ] that are greater than a specified element elem.

I have written my code as:

```
public class GenericMethods<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    
    public static < E > void printArray( E[] inputArray ) {
        // Display array elements
        for(E element : inputArray) {
            System.out.printf("%s ", element);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static < E > void countArray( E[] inputArray, int elem) {
        int i=0;
        for(E element : inputArray){
            if(elem>element)
                i++;
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }


   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
      System.out.println("\nArray contains:");
      printArray(intArray);
      int elem=0;
      System.out.println("Enter the specified number: ");
      elem = sc.nextInt();
      countArray(intArray, elem); 
      
   }
}
```

I get the following errors:

[error: bad operand types for binary operator '>'
if(elem>element)
^
first type:  int
second type: E
where E is a type-variable:
E extends Object declared in method countArray(E[],int)
1 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQBsh.jpg)

Comment: You should in fact use `GenericMethods<E extends Number>`

Answer (score 2):

One way is to require that your generic type parameter `E` is a `Number`.

Then you can use `Number`'s `intValue()` method to convert each element of the array to an `int`, which can be compared to `elem`.

```
public static <E extends Number> void countArray(E[] inputArray, int elem) {
    int i = 0;
    for (E element : inputArray) {
        if(elem > element.intValue ())
            i++;
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you cant use `>` operator on object
you can do as Eran said or ensure E implements Comparable and use `compareTo()`

```
<E extends Comparable>
if(element.compareTo(new Integer(elem))<0)
```